# How to cancel the sound when a button is clicked?

Tags: android, audio, button

I am developing an Android application. How do I cancel the sound when a button is clicked?

Comment: show some relevant code how you are playing audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you mean the default touch feedback sound?
It's from the phone's setting and not related to a particular app.

Comment: Thank you ,I know how to solve it